# I am trying to import firestore databse to big query using extension, however the sub collections are not getting populated, have tried multiple ways

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sync Big Query with Firestore Database. I have used the extension to import Firestore DB to Big Query however the subcollections are not getting exported to Big Query. I have even tried to make multiple instances of each subcollection that way I do have subcollection data but the data is disconnected from other tables. I want all the data in one table so whenever Firestore gets updated Big Query also gets updated. Have been stuck on this for weeks, mean a lot if I can get step by step guidance as to what I should do. I just got started with Big Query and working on a Cloud Platform. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you used the [import script](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-bigquery-export/guides/IMPORT_EXISTING_DOCUMENTS.md) in order to populate your bigquery instance? AFAIK, the extension only sends the content of documents that have been changed, it does not export your full dataset of existing documents into BigQuery. You need to do that through the import script

Comment: yes I have done that as well